# VIM macro for interacting with multiple tabs

Tags: vim, function, macros, tabs

This is what I want to do using GVIM 7.3:

1. open a file in new tab (first tab)
2. get all lines which contain a pattern -> insert them to a register/clipboard
3. open a new tab (second tab)
4. paste the code from clipboard
5. do some regex replace process in the second tab.

I can manually execute commands one by one successfully.

I even can do commands in sequence using this sample :

```
:let @b="This Value should be pasted in second tab"  | :set dir=$TEMP | :tabe tabname | "bp | :%s/tab/tab and replaced in second tab/gi
```

but when I record them into a macro; The macro stops at step 3

Is there special technique dealing with function/macro that access multiple tabs

Thank you.

this is the commands sample

```
    :let @b="This Value should be pasted in second tab" 
    :set dir=$TEMP
    ":tabe tabName
    "bp 
:%s/tab/tab and replaced in second tab/gi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong syntax on your first line: Ex commands should not start with `:`: you use `:` to open command line, it is not an Ex command designator. So, all what `"bp` does in this sequence is commenting the whole line starting with `"`. If you want to execute normal command `"bp`, use `execute 'normal! "bp'`, but you can also paste with `put b`. Function that can do what you want (to be put in `~/.vimrc`):

```
function! FindToTab(regex)
    let @b=""
    execute 'g/'.escape(a:regex, '/').'/.yank B'
    set dir=$TEMP
    tabe tabName
    put b
    %s/tab/tab and replaced in second tab/gi
endfunction
noremap <special> ,r :<C-u>call FindToTab(input("What to find? /", @/))<CR>
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks for your quick help. I will try your answer before marking as answer